# How to convert this Kotlin code (containing some method and some class) to java

Tags: java, kotlin

please convert this Kotlin code to java.
here "someMethod" is some function and "someClass" is some class

```
var someMethod: ((someClass) -> Unit)? = null

private val someListener = View.OnClickListener {
    someMethod?.invoke(it.tag as someClass)
}
```

Comment: How about `Tools` -> `Kotlin` -> `Show Kotlin Bytecode` -> `Decompile to Java`? Obviously you'd need to create a interface instead of KFunction (Kotlin Lambdas).

Comment: Hi Animesh, does this method work in Android Studio 3.6.3?

Comment: @YESVGOJOBS yes it does